# Docker build can't reach the internet

Tags: 22.04, internet, compiling, docker, error-handling

when I run docker build -t test . it gives me error connection time out, how can I solve this issue, please? I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3
[connection time out][1]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the firewall so when I stopped the firewall, everything worked fine